# Set form-data post parameter in Swagger inspector

Tags: php, api, yii2, swagger, swagger-php

I have just started swagger for documented api. I am using Swagger inspector for execute the api, before that I was using Postman. I am passing the data in Swagger body but not getting the data, same thing works in Postman but not working here.

Moreover get request works with Swagger but post is not working properly.

Getting response in Postman:

[image]

Same thing not working in Swagger:

[image]

I have already set the header, but not getting my parameter in post.
[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: you are setting headers in postman as i can see there is a count badge visible of `2` headers added you need to add them while making a request from swagger too, show the headers from both the applications or match them the same, as your api endpoint is providing the response but not showing the form data that you are sending

Comment: can you mark the answer as correct if it worked for you?

Comment: how are you sending the parameters ?

Comment: in body like this : 
{
    'uname' : 123,
}

Comment: are you using single quotes to send the json `{ 'uname' : 123, }` thats not a valid json. `{ "uname" : 123, }` this is . you should use double quotes and can you add the `config/main.php`  from your `api` folder, haveyou configured the json parser?

Comment: do mark the answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not setting the **Request Headers** `Content-Type` in swagger, as you need to send the `POST` request you need to send the data via the **Body** tab and to send the data you need to specify the content type for the request body so do the following

- Add a `Content-Type : application/json` header from the `Authentication&Headers` tab like below 
  [image]
- if you are using any authentication headers for the request when using `postman` add them too
- Now go to the `Body` tab

[image]

and add the following

```
{
    "userName": "123",
}
```

That's all you need to do now click send and it will show you the data sent, just select any format for the request Headers and then provide the data in that format. Below are the supported formats

[image]

Comment: I have already set this but in response, I am getting the same result, I have edited the question and added the new screenshot.